# I don't think I understand how to calculate the distance of when objects are passing each other

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, velocity, distance

You are driving a SUV with constant velocity of 22m/s. At a moment, you notice a truck 200 meters ahead of you, moving in the same direction with constant velocity 18 m/s. How far your car should travel until you catch the truck?

Comment: To help us answer your question better, can you please clarify the following: What specifically is confusing for you? What have you already tried with the problem?

Comment: If they both meet in $50 sec$ how far will the suv travel?

Comment: I've realized what was confusing me about this and have answered the question. Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Calculate their relative velocity. Determine how long it will take for both vehicles to meet over that distance. From there it will be trivial to calculate the distance the SUV travels.